# Getting ExceptionInInitializerError when loading mapping for a resource

Tags: hibernate, tomcat7, jsf-2.2

**Intro:**

I've started with Java Web, using JSF 2.2 (Mojarra), SLF4J as logging framework, and implemented the simple example called **[guess number](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets003.htm)**.

I've expanded this to include a database so that I get my hands on JDBC.
So into the database, I've inserted the valid numbers that the `NumberDAO` (not the Bean of the facelet) checks to see if the guess was correct.

I've also added a new facelet that allows the user to insert a new valid number into the database (using a `NumberDAO` class).

*Up to now, this worked just fine.*

---

**What I need to do and have done already:**

The thing now, is that I want to integrate Hibernate *(version: 4.2)*.
This is its [configuration](http://pastebin.com/XuY4tzpA).

And [this is the mapping](http://pastebin.com/0Gdbp9PN) for the resource (*NumberEndity is a simple POJO created by IntelliJ*).

This line is into the static code block of `NumberDAO` class:
`session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();`

And this is the [HibernateUtil](http://pastebin.com/ZQZgKs4z) class.

---

**Problems:**

(**Edit:**  This is the last output of Hibernate - before the errors occur:
`2014-08-19 11:33:24 INFO HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: guessNumber/models/NumberEntity.hbm.xml`)

Now, I'm getting these exceptions when I'm running it (**if the mapping is commented out, it loads fine)**, during the initialization phase:
**Firstly this one:** [Stack trace of 1st and 2nd Exceptions](http://pastebin.com/0PubR3bB)

**And lastly this one:** (*which should be related to the fact that during the initialization of NumberDAO there was an Exception*)
[StackTrace that is shown at the facelet at the browser, as well](http://pastebin.com/8qXmYh9W)

---

I'm at a loss of figuring out how to resolve the error.
I got up to:

1. Finding that when commenting out the mapping at `hibernate.cfg.xml` the error won't occur
2. The error occurs in `configuration.configure();` of `HibernateUtil`.

Comment: The complete stack trace would be helpful in providing insight as to who's causing this all.

Comment: @BalusC: I've just added the stack traces.

Comment: The complete stack trace, please. The root cause (the NPE) is of interest. All others are just consequences.

Comment: OK, the NPE indicates indeed a different problem. JSF's own exception handler failed to handle the exception (which Mojarra version exactly?). I'm still not seeing why `NumberDAO` couldn't be initialized. Is there no root cause below `NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: @Chris show NumberEntity and NumberDAO class.

Comment: @BalusC No, I couldn't see any `caused by` or root cause. I think I solved it though, I had left some of the previous initialization segment for the JDBC connections. I removed them all, and now the application loads fine. _Now I am looking into another hibernate related exception I've run into._   
It did help me that you've said that you couldn't see why NumberDAO isn't initialized, thanks for that